# Is there an alternative to template literals in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, multiline, multilinestring, template-literals

I have a bunch of strings which consist of code concatenated that I need to put in a single JavaScript variable.

`` `template literals` `` was clearly the way to go, and it worked fine. But IE doesn't support it.

Is there any way to avoid using `` `template literals` `` and still get a multiline string?

Comment: Yes, transpile.

Comment: Yes, use a real browser...

Comment: Lol I do, the people who use the website don't.. If it depended on me, I would just put a popup saying not to use it but well. How does transpiling works?

Comment: Check [the MDN page on template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Multi-line_strings). It shows the similarity between `"abc\ndef"` and ` `abc [line break] def` `

Comment: Strings of code? Uh oh